# OS with newer Guest additions running on older VirtualBox host — is it possible?

Tags: virtualbox, upgrade, dualboot

I have a dual-boot system: Kubuntu with VirtualBox 6.1.10 host and Manjaro with VirtualBox 6.1.16 host. There are Guest Additions from VirtualBox 6.1.10 installed on my guest OS.

When I start my guest from the Manjaro's VirtualBox (version 6.1.16), it suggests to upgrade the Guest Additions. But I'm afraid to make the upgrade.

Is it safe to upgrade the Guest Additions if I need to run the guest under the older version of the VirtualBox host? Will my Kubuntu's VirtualBox (version 6.1.10) be able to start the guest with newer Guest Additions installed?

Comment: The latest version of VirtualBox is 6.1.16. How are you checking the version?

Comment: Anyway, just make a VM snapshot, upgrade and check if it works (it should). If it doesn't, rollback to snapshot.

Comment: @gronostaj, about version numbers, yes, thank you! 16 = 6.1.16, and 10 = 6.1.10. Initial post corrected.